# php search by age range

Tags: php, search

I don't know how make in this script age range search in database users have tabla with name "age" and age show as numeral and I need make form where search users by age from to age?

Here is code please help me :)

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
  <label>City</label>
  <select name="city">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <?php
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY city ORDER BY city";
         $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
             echo "<option value='".$row["city"]."'".($row["city"]==$_REQUEST["city"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["city"]."</option>";
         }
     ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
  <a href="index.php">reset</a>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>username</strong></td>
    <td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>e-mail</strong></td>
    <td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>city</strong></td>    
  </tr>
  <?php
     if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
         $search_string = " AND (full_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";    
     }
     if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
        $search_city = " AND city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";   
     }

    if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
    } else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
    } else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
    } else {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city;
    }

    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
       ?>
      <tr>

        <td><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
    } else {
     ?>
     <tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
     <?php  
     }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use mysql methods as it is deprecated and will be removed in the future.


I am posting the code using `PDO`.

You can check out the documentation of PDO here [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

You can query as:

```
try{
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db_name', 'username', 'password');
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $range = $_POST['age_range'];
  $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE age <= $range");
  $query->exec();
}
catch(Exception $e){
  echo "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
  // you might not use the above code in your production code
  // as might want not to show the errors and redirect to another custom error page
}
```

### Explanation

In the above code we make a connection to the db using pdo and set attribute to start the error reporting system and the
variable range gets the value of the posted age field value provided by the user and stores it. And in the query string it gets all the entries which have the value of age column less than the user given age.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: To comment I need more than 50 reputation

Comment: That's not that far, @GourabNag ;)

Comment: @GourabNag You can post this as an answer, but you have to elaborate it more. You could explain what's the problem in the asker's code, and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, because these are deprecated. Use the `mysqli` extension or preferable `PDO`.

With this extensions, you can create a prepared statement, which prevents an SQL injection.

Here are an code example:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql://host=localhost;dbname=test_db', 'myuser', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE age < ?');
$stmt->execute([$age]);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```